# Blender shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have a question about shrinkwrap.
I'm started mastering car course by cg masters I'm doing fine but and I can't understand one thing.
As English is not my main language and I'm bad with it I need some explanation please, I don't understand the author correctly.
1) We have GUIDE mesh and BASE mesh. Which one is main and which one is the second ?
2) We make main mesh and then copy it to apply shrinkwrap on it mesh later.
2) Guide mesh is main and  must have subdivision level 2 and base mesh subdivision level 4 ? Or vice versa ? I'm stuck.
As I understand the process: we make simple mesh (guide) in subdivision 2, copy it, then we make detailed mesh (base) from copy in subdivision 4, apply shrinkwrap modifier with guide mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CG Masters explained their modelling techniques much more thoroughly in their *Hard Surface Modelling* course series. I'll try to explain it here.

They are using the *Shrinkwrap Modifier* to avoid shading issues. When you are using many modifiers such as *Boolean* and *Subdivide Surface* modifiers, it is common to encounter strange/unwanted shading (such as creases and sharp edges) on the surfaces.

Thus, to avoid those shading issues, they create two meshes, a **base/guide** mesh and a **detailed copy** mesh. The base mesh has a minimal amount of detail on it, its purpose is to provide the proper shape and shading to the detailed mesh. The copy mesh has all of the details, such as boolean cutouts, on it. Since this results in shading issues, they use the *Shrinkwrap Modifier* to stick the *Copy mesh* onto the *Base Mesh*. Doing so transfers all of the normals from the *base* to the *copy*, fixing the shading while keeping the detail.

Comment: So base = guide, okay. Thanks for answering dude.